# Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm getting the following error when trying to use react-chartjs-2:

> ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.modern.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in 'C:\Users\win10\Desktop\project\covid-19-tracker\node_modules\react-chartjs-2\dist'

As seen in package.json, the versions of the packages I'm working with are:

```
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your chartjs package to v3 (latest: 3.4.1) or downgrade the react wrapper to I think 2.11.2 should work since its the last release before major number increase